# Запрос json к веб-серверу отрабатывает на эмуляторе в Android Sudio, но не работает на реальном устройстве

Tags: java, android, sql, json, android-studio

В мобильном приложении, разрабатываемом в Android Studio на Java, выполняется обращение веб-серверу с запросом на проверку подключения к БД MS SQL Server. В браузере и запущенном на эмуляторе приложении результат запроса возвращает true. При развертывании приложения на реальном устройстве результат - false (из-за ошибки выполнения запроса). В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: проблема в отсутсвии лога

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решена. В файле `AndroidManifest.xml` прописал

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```